# How to make app available only to people with link in google play console?

Tags: android, google-play

I have an app which is published as closed testing in google play. But it is available **only** to testers whose emails have been added. But I want the app should be visible and installable to the people/testers **ONLY TO THE PEOPLE WITH THE APP LINK.** Which means that anyone who has the link can see and download the app but, if people search on the playstore, it should not be visible to them. How can I do so?

Comment: Its Not possible.

Comment: I dont think Google Play offer such a visibility options, what have you try so far and where you get the idea you can do this?

Comment: I read about closed and open testing of google play docs. The open testing lets any user to test it while the closed testing allows only to the testers whose email is mentioned by the developer. But I want something that makes it available to anyone with whom we share the link. Basically dont want it to appear on the search result

Comment: Either use closed testing or an internal testing.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

What you looking for can be archived in Play store private Android apps in Google Play, but you have to have one of these accounts types

Supported editions for this feature:

1. Frontline
2. Business Starter
3. Business Standard
4. Business Plus
5. Enterprise
6. Education Fundamentals, Education Standard, Teaching and Learning Upgrade, and Education Plus;
7. G Suite Basic and G Suite Business
8. Essentials
9. Cloud Identity Free and Cloud Identity Premium.

If you have one of these accounts types associated with your play store account then you can list private Play Store listing of your app

on How to do it, please take a look here

https://support.google.com/a/answer/2494992?hl=en